# Sass if inside each

Tags: list, variables, for-loop, sass, each

I'm trying to get specific selectors from the following list, to have two properties, and all the other selectors, have a single property.

I tried the following code, but it seems, every selector, gets both properties defined on the class inside the if function.

```
$items: (one 20% 30%) (two 12% 24%) (three 34% 32%) (four 45% 50%);

@each $item in $items {
  @if #{nth($item, 1)} == one or three {
    .#{nth($item, 1)} {
      left: #{nth($item, 2)};
      bottom: #{nth($item, 3)};
    }
  } @else {
    .#{nth($item, 1)} {
      left: #{nth($item, 2)};
    }
  }
}
```

The result I'm trying to achieve is:

```
.one {
  left: 20%;
  bottom: 30%;
}

.two {
  left: 12%;
}

.three {
  left: 34%;
  bottom: 32%;
}

.four {
  left: 45%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your logic.  Your if statement has 2 expressions:  `(nth($item, 1) == one) or (three)`.  The `three` part is always evaluating to true.

```
$items: (one 20% 30%) (two 12% 24%) (three 34% 32%) (four 45% 50%);

@each $item in $items {
  @if nth($item, 1) == one or nth($item, 1) == three {
    .#{nth($item, 1)} {
      left: #{nth($item, 2)};
      bottom: #{nth($item, 3)};
    }
  } @else {
    .#{nth($item, 1)} {
      left: #{nth($item, 2)};
    }
  }
}
```